# "javax.swing.JPanel cannot be cast" exception, confusing

Tags: java, image, exception

i am trying to assign an image to a grid layout and i found the solution on stack overflow. However ive changed my code since than and now its not working and im getting the cannot be cast exception and im not sure why.

Below is the method that throws the exception, specifically the imagePanel line:

```
public void setVehicle(int x, int y, Vehicle vehicle) {
    this.vehicles[x][y] = vehicle;
    ImageIcon image;
    if (vehicle != null) {
        image = vehicle.getImage();
    } else {
        image = null;
    }
    ((ImagePanel) this.pnlCars.getComponent(x + (y - 1) * (this.vehicles.length - 1))).setImage(image);}
```

This is the image panel class below:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
private ImageIcon image;

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (image != null) {
        // Center icon
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        int iconWidth = image.getIconWidth();
        int iconHeight = image.getIconHeight();
        g.drawImage(image.getImage(), (width - iconWidth) / 2, (height - iconHeight) / 2, null);
    }
}

public void setImage(ImageIcon image) {
    this.image = image;
    this.repaint();
}
```

}

this it the error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JPanel cannot be cast to carparkingprogram.gui.ImagePanel
    at carparkingprogram.gui.CarParkPanel.setVehicle(CarParkPanel.java:197)
    at carparkingprogram.gui.CarParkPanel$7$1.actionPerformed(CarParkPanel.java:325)
```

Would anyone be able to help?

This is the complete code, obviously i've tried to make it as small as possible, so ive only included the cars part.

```
public static int ROWS_LARGE = 1;
public static int ROWS_SMALL = 3;
public static int ROWS = ROWS_LARGE + ROWS_SMALL;
public static int COLUMNS = 4;
public Vehicle[][] vehicles = new Vehicle[ROWS][COLUMNS];


public CarParkPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    pnlButtons = new JPanel();
    pnlButtons.setLayout(null);
    pnlButtons.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlButtons, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    pnlButtons.add(btnAddCar);
    addCarMethod();

    this.add(pnlButtons);


    this.pnlLorry = new JPanel();
    this.pnlLorry.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS_LARGE, COLUMNS));
    this.pnlLorry.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

    this.pnlCars = new JPanel();
    this.pnlCars.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS_SMALL, COLUMNS));
    this.pnlCars.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

//This is the code to create the grid panel that the images are added to
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++) {
            JPanel pnlVehicle = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            pnlVehicle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
            pnlVehicle.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(column, (row * ROWS)));

            if (row < ROWS_LARGE) {
                this.pnlLorry.add(pnlVehicle);
            } else {
                this.pnlCars.add(pnlVehicle);
            }
        }
    }


    this.add(pnlButtons, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.pnlVehicles = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    this.pnlVehicles.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
    this.pnlVehicles.add(this.pnlLorry, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.pnlVehicles.add(this.pnlCars, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    this.add(this.pnlVehicles, BorderLayout.EAST);


}

public int[] findEmptySpace(int start, int end) {
    for (int row = 0; row < vehicles.length; row++) {
        for (int column = start; column < end; column++) {
            //Check if space is empty
            if (this.getVehicle(row, column) == null) {
                return new int[]{
                    row,
                    column
                };
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public void setVehicle(int x, int y, Vehicle vehicle) {
    this.vehicles[x][y] = vehicle;

    //TODO: Render vehicle in GUI. Check for null and remove
    ImageIcon image;
    if (vehicle != null) {
        image = vehicle.getImage();
    } else {
        image = null;
    }
    ((ImagePanel) this.pnlCars.getComponent(x + (y - 1) * (this.vehicles.length - 1))).setImage(image);

    //TODO: Update totals

}

public Vehicle getVehicle(int x, int y) {
    return this.vehicles[x][y];
}

private void addCarMethod() {
    btnAddCar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //TODO: Create car input form.
            //REQUIREMENTS: registration, length, disabled


            final int[] value = findEmptySpace(1, vehicles.length);
            if (value != null) {
                //SHOW FORM

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add Car");
                frame.setSize(350, 150);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                Labels = new GridLayout(4, 2);
                FormLayout = new GridLayout(2, 1);

                pnlForm = new JPanel();
                pnlFormButton = new JPanel();
                frame.setLayout(FormLayout);
                frame.add(pnlForm);
                frame.add(pnlFormButton);
                pnlForm.setLayout(null);

                pnlForm.setLayout(Labels);
                JLabel reg = new JLabel("Registration Number:");
                pnlForm.add(reg);

                final JTextField regTxt = new JTextField(20);
                pnlForm.add(regTxt);

                JLabel length = new JLabel("Length: ");
                pnlForm.add(length);

                final JTextField lengthTxt = new JTextField(20);
                pnlForm.add(lengthTxt);

                JLabel disBadge = new JLabel("Disabled Badge: ");
                pnlForm.add(disBadge);

                final JTextField disBadgeTxt = new JTextField(20);
                pnlForm.add(disBadgeTxt);

                JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
                pnlFormButton.setLayout(FormLayout);
                pnlFormButton.add(ok);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        String regNumber = regTxt.getText();
                        System.out.println("ok");
                        double length = Double.parseDouble(lengthTxt.getText());
                        boolean BadgeBoolean;

                        if (disBadgeTxt.equals("yes")) {
                            BadgeBoolean = true;
                        } else {
                            BadgeBoolean = false;
                        }

                        Car vehicle = new Car(regNumber, length, BadgeBoolean, 1);
                        System.out.println(String.valueOf(value[0]) + ":" + String.valueOf(value[1]));
                        setVehicle(value[0], value[1], vehicle);

                        frame.dispose();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                warningMethod();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Probably it would help if you could share how do you add components to the `CarParkPanel.pnlCars` field.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that this line:

```
this.pnlCars.getComponent(x + (y - 1) * (this.vehicles.length - 1))
```

is returning a JPanel instance, not an ImagePanel instance, and the reason for this is not shown in the code you've posted. Using `getComponent(...)` in this way is a dangerous and brittle thing to do, and a better way may be available if we could know more about your program. For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

As an aside, that line of offending code,

```
((ImagePanel) this.pnlCars.getComponent(x + (y - 1) * (this.vehicles.length - 1)))
      .setImage(image);}
```

is way too long, and tries to do too much, making debugging more difficult than it needs to be. Code real estate is cheap, and so break it up into several lines, to make reading and debugging easier.

---

**Edit**

You're adding JPanels (here called pnlVehicle) to your pnlCars JPanel object:

```
this.pnlCars.add(pnlVehicle);
```

So it makes perfect sense that should you try to extract a component from the pnlVehicle JPanel, it will in fact be a JPanel and not an ImagePanel (whatever that is). Your error should not surprise you.

Comment: I've just uploaded the full code (that i've compressed) :)

Comment: @RebeccaWilde: thank you, but better to create and post a [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a non-compilable and non-runnable code snippet. Please read the link as it will explain why this is important and what the requirements are.

Comment: Thank you. i managed to sort out where i went wrong!The image panel part was a class that ran assigned the image to the jpanel, and i just hadn't properly initialized it earlier on in the program!